# Как использовать метод @override в Java с extends?

Tags: java, методы, override

Здравтсуйте.
Есть четрые интересующих класса, мне интересно как вывести @Override значение "System.out.println("Woooooooooof!");" в данном коде:

```
abstract public class Animal {
    abstract public void greeting();
}
```

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void greeting() {
        System.out.println("Woof!");
    }

    public void greeting(Dog another) {
        System.out.println("Woooooooooof!");
    }
}
```

```
public class BigDog extends Dog {
    @Override
    public void greeting() {
        System.out.println("Woow!");
    }

    @Override
    public void greeting(Dog another) {
        System.out.println("Woooooowwwww!");
    }
}
```

```
public class TestAnimal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Using the subclasses
        Cat cat1 = new Cat();
        Animal cat2 = new Cat();
        Dog dog1 = new Dog();
        Animal dog2 = new Dog();
        BigDog bigdog1 = new BigDog();
        Animal bigdog2 = new BigDog();

        Animal[] animal = {cat1, cat2, dog1, dog2, bigdog1, bigdog2};

        for (Animal a: animal) {
            a.greeting();
        }

    }
}
```

Я помню это делается как то через inastanceof, но не помню как именно это работает.

Благодраю за помощь!

Comment: Что вы хотите увидеть при выполнении программы? И класс `Cat` вы не показали

Comment: вы хотите вызывать метод  только собак, или же только больших собак?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю можно как-то так, если, конечно, я Вас правильно понял:

```
package com.somepackage;

public class TestAnimal {

    public interface Animal {
        void greeting();
        void greeting(Animal another);
    }

    public static class Dog implements Animal {
        @Override
        public void greeting() {
            System.out.println("Woof!");
        }

        @Override
        public void greeting(Animal another) {
            System.out.println("Woooooooooof!");
        }
    }

    public static class BigDog extends Dog {
        @Override
        public void greeting() {
            System.out.println("Woow!");
        }

        @Override
        public void greeting(Animal another) {
            System.out.println("Woooooowwwww!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Using the subclasses
        Dog dog1 = new Dog();
        Animal dog2 = new Dog();
        BigDog bigdog1 = new BigDog();
        Animal bigdog2 = new BigDog();

        Animal[] animals = {dog1, dog2, bigdog1, bigdog2};

        for (Animal animal : animals) {
            animal.greeting();
            for (Animal anotherAnimal: animals) {
                if (!animal.equals(anotherAnimal)) {
                    animal.greeting(anotherAnimal);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestAnimal {

    public interface Animal {
        void greeting();
        void greeting(Animal another);
    }

    public static class Dog implements Animal {
        @Override
        public void greeting() {
            System.out.println("Woof!");
        }

        @Override
        public void greeting(Animal another) {
            System.out.println("Woooooooooof!");
        }
    }

    public static class BigDog extends Dog {
        @Override
        public void greeting() {
            System.out.println("Woow!");
        }

        @Override
        public void greeting(Animal another) {
            System.out.println("Woooooowwwww!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Using the subclasses
        Dog dog1 = new Dog();
        Animal dog2 = new Dog();
        BigDog bigdog1 = new BigDog();
        Animal bigdog2 = new BigDog();

        Animal[] animals = {dog1, dog2, bigdog1, bigdog2};

        for (Animal animal : animals) {
            if (animal instanceof Dog && !(animal instanceof BigDog))

            animal.greeting(new Dog());
            else
                animal.greeting();
        }

    }
}
```